# Sample Objective-C code to queue thread-safe callbacks efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I was checking Apple's GCD guide and found it quite lengthy for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm working on an iOS SpriteKit game (using Objective-C) and I need to use concurrency for 2 simple tasks:

- Show a progress bar right after launch while performing all initialization logic in a separate thread/queue. I know how to achieve this using classic posix threads but is there an equivalent in GCD that would be significantly more efficient?
- Regularly save user progress under a separate thread/queue to avoid affecting UI frame rate/responsiveness. It sounds like GCD queues could be a perfect fit here, and so my question is how can I queue callback blocks under a secondary thread using GCD?

In both cases there's no risk of concurrency related data corruption, and I have no need to perform cross-thread communication (no synchronization whatsoever needed).

An answer with sample code would be perfect.

Comment: Sounds somewhat over-engineered as showing the progress bar is pretty trivial and can probably be done only in the main thread (if SpriteKit is anything like UIKit) and user progress can be saved to memory until the user reaches a rest point where it can be written to storage.  I don't see the need for background threads/tasks/whatever at all for those requirements.

Comment: I think what is meant is that there is some intensive initialisation that needs to be done in the background while being able to update a progress indicator for the user while the game is loading.

Comment: Besides what George mentioned, I need to run my initialization code at launch before the game starts. Keeping it in the main thread under my App Delegate application:did/willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: causes the app icon to freeze for a moment at launch until initialization has finished; a secondary thread with a progress bar prevents that. Regarding user progress saving though, you're probably right I'm re-thinking my design there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that it would be much more efficient, but makes for nicer code...

The system provides some default background queues with gcd that you can use rather than creating your own, and then it will handle off-loading things on the queues to other threads as-and-when it thinks that it would be most beneficial. To get this working is super simple:

---- SWIFT ----

```
// Dispatch a block of code to a background queue
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) { 
    // Do initialisation in the background
    ...
    // Call back to the main queue if you want to update any UI when you are done
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Set progress indicator to complete?
    }
}
// Handle the progress indicator while the initialisation is happening in the background
```

---- OBJ-C ----

```
// Dispatch a block of code to a background queue
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, { 
    // Do initialisation in the background
    ...
    // Call back to the main queue if you want to update any UI when you are done
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Set progress indicator to complete?
    });
});
// Handle the progress indicator while the initialisation is happening in the background
```

So nice and simply, this dispatches the initialisation onto a background queue, and calls back to the main thread once it is complete, then carries on to update the progress indicator.

Always important to remember you MUST NOT update the UI from any queue other than the main queue.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can be more clear.